# rename file names using folder name but keep the digit same

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I want to rename my files in the subdirectories using the folder name. My files are like this format

```
fastqjoin
    un1
        fasta
        fastq
    un2
        fasta
        fastq
```

and I want to change it to

```
foldername
    un1
        fasta
        fastq
    un2
        fasta
        fastq
```

I found this script can change the filename using the folder name but I want to add the regular expression so that it can change all files in one script

```
for subdir in *; do mv $subdir/fastqjoin.un1.fasta $subdir/$subdir.un1.fasta; done;
```

I have tried replacing the script with `un[0-9].fast/D, un/d.fast/D` but none of them work. For example:

```
f`or subdir in *; do mv $subdir/fastqjoin.un[0-9].fast/D $subdir/$subdir.un[0-9].fast/D; done;`
```

Comment: Show us your folder structure where you have the files.

Comment: The folder structure is directory/subdirectory/file and my terminal is at directory.

Comment: It looks to me like you just want to rename the `fastqjoin` folder to `foldername`.

Comment: @4castle yes, but I want to keep un[digit] and the same file format. So fastqjoin.un1.fastq, fastqjoin.un2.fastq, fastqjoin.un1.fasta, fastqjoin.un2.fasta will be changed it to  foldername.un1.fasta, foldername.un2.fasta, foldername.un1.fastq, foldername.un2.fastq.

Comment: I'm going to edit your question so it's in a more readable format. Hopefully that will clear things up.

Comment: If you don't want to change any of the contained files, then don't even worry about making a regex that looks at them. Just rename the top level folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `${variable#fastqjoin}` to remove `fastqjoin` from the beginning of the variable, and another loop to iterate over the files:

```
for subdir in *; do
    for pth in $subdir/*; do
        file=`basename $pth`;
        mv $pth $subdir/$subdir${file#fastqjoin};
    done;
done
```